# Linux Mint 19.3 Dual Monitor on HD6870 stopped working

Tags: linux-mint, multi-monitor, amd-graphics

I built a desktop for my in-laws using second hand parts. It has been humming along since last November or so with Linux Mint 19 (now 19.3). They just moved shortly after the lock downs for COVID-19 started in March, and when they plugged the system back in, the second display didn't work (it always had before without any effort beyond the system settings display configuration dialog). Even worse they could login to the login screen, and then the system switches that monitor to the secondary logical display. This leaves them without any UI elements except their background and the right click context menu. I have access to the machine remotely over SSH, so I have updated it as far as it will go and I have run dpkg-reconfigure on the applicable (or what I think are applicable) Xorg display config packages.

I just visited for a short bit over the weekend and I am stumped by it. If I only have one monitor attached, I can login and get a fully usable system on the single display. When I attach the second display, the first display goes dark and the new display lights up as the logical secondary. It stays this way even if I unplug the primary display. It doesn't matter which monitor is physically connected first at boot or to which of the two connections I'm using. The first one connected is the logical primary and works fine alone, but goes dark as soon as the second display is attached to the graphics card.

The system is as follows:
System: Kernel: 5.3.0-51-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Console: tty 0 Distro: Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia
Machine: Type: Desktop Mobo: ASRock model: AB350M-HDV serial:  UEFI [Legacy]: American Megatrends v: P5.50
date: 12/20/2018
CPU: Quad Core: AMD Ryzen 5 1400 type: MT MCP speed: 1374 MHz min/max: 1550/3200 MHz
Graphics: Device-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Barts XT [Radeon HD 6870] driver: radeon v: kernel
Display: server: X.org 1.19.6 driver: ati,radeon unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa tty: 179x97
Message: Advanced graphics data unavailable in console. Try -G --display
Network: Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet driver: r8169
Drives: Local Storage: total: 2.27 TiB used: 134.55 GiB (5.8%)
Info: Processes: 230 Uptime: 3d 5h 02m Memory: 7.77 GiB used: 2.73 GiB (35.1%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Shell: bash
inxi: 3.0.32

The specific GPU is:[XFX Black HD6870](https://c1.neweggimages.com/ProductImage/14-150-521-03.jpg)

The monitors are AOC 1080P 22" and are attched to the HDMI port and the bottom DVI port via DVI to HDMI adapter (bottom meaning as installed, closest to the fan side in the image above). I cannot use the DVI port directly adjacent to the HDMI port because the HDMI cable and DVI to HDMI adapter are too large to not interfere with one another.